# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me da este error en la linea 12 de mi codigo, pero no lo veo la logica porque en esa linea no tengo ningun '>'. 
Alguien que me pueda ayudar? 
Codigo:

```
cas = int(input())
while(cas != 0):
  hangar = input()
  hangar2 = hangar.split()
  avion = int(input())
  av = input()
  avion2 = av.split()
  a = 0
  cA = 0
  c = 0 
  while(avion > 0):
    maxi = max(hangar2)
    ha = hangar2.index(maxi)
    # print(ha, maxi, avion2[cA], hangar2[ha])
    if((int(hangar2[ha])-int(avion2[cA]) >= 0)):
      # print("entro")
      # print(hangar2[ha], avion2[cA])
      hangar2[ha] = int(hangar2[ha]) - int(avion2[cA])
      # print(hangar2[ha])
      avion2.pop(cA)
    # print(avion2)
    # print(hangar2)
    if(avion2 == ""):
      c = 1
    # ha += 1
    avion -= 1
  if(c == 1):
    print("SI")
  else:
    print("NO")
  cas = int(input())
```

Error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
 File "main.py", line 12, in 
  
        maxi = max(hangar2)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Buenas. Te esta indicando que no se pueden comprar una `String` y un `int`. Tendrias que hacer un cast. Te quedaria algo asi: `while(int(avion) > 0):`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero el error no es en esa linea. 
Igualmente, muchas gracias por intentar ayudar!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado!
Cuanto hacia la primera vuelta de bucle, dejaba el hangar2[ha] como int y no como str, para solucionarlo he añadido esta linea:

```
hangar2[ha] = str(hangar2[ha])
```

Entonces el codigo queda asi:

```
cas = int(input())
while(cas != 0):
  hangar = input()
  hangar2 = hangar.split()
  avion = int(input())
  av = input()
  avion2 = av.split()
  a = 0
  cA = 0
  c = 0 
  while(int(avion) > 0):
    maxi = max(hangar2)
    ha = hangar2.index(maxi)
    # print(ha, maxi, avion2[cA], hangar2[ha])
    if((int(hangar2[ha])-int(avion2[cA]) >= 0)):
      # print("entro")
      # print(hangar2[ha], avion2[cA])
      hangar2[ha] = int(hangar2[ha]) - int(avion2[cA])
      hangar2[ha] = str(hangar2[ha])
      # print(hangar2[ha])
      avion2.pop(cA)
    # print(avion2)
    # print(hangar2)
    cA += 1
    # if(avion2 == ""):
    #   c = 1
    # ha += 1    
    avion -= 1
    # hangar2 = str(int(hangar2))
  if(c == 1):
    print("SI")
  else:
    print("NO")
  cas = int(input())
```

Comment: Auto responderte es algo que se promueve en SOes, así genial si has conseguido encontrar la solución por ti mismo y la compartes. Tras esperar un tiempo podrás *aceptar* la respuesta y así la pregunta quedará marcada como *respondida*, lo que hace no sea necesario modificar el título de la pregunta para indicar que está solucionada. Un saludo y bienvenido a SOes

Comment: De acuerdo! Muchas gracias! @PabloLozano