# ERROR: if self.max_length is not None and choice_max_length > self.max_length: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int'

Tags: python, mysql, django

Estoy tratando de ejecutar las migraciones en django por visual studio y me genera este error.

Aquí mi Codigo:

```
from django.db import models

COPYRIGTH = 'RIG'
COPYLEFT = 'LEF'
CREATIVE_COMMONS = 'CC'

LICENSES = (
    (COPYRIGTH, "Copyrigth"),
    (COPYLEFT, "Copyleft"),
    (CREATIVE_COMMONS, "Cretive Commons")
    )



class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    url = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default ="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    license = models.CharField(max_length="3", choices=LICENSES)
```

Answer (score 0):

¿es posible que el título de tu pregunta esté incompleto? Normalmente, ese error salta cuando estas comparando dos variables con diferente tipo de dato, por tanto, una de tu variable sera Integer, pero la otra de otro tipo (que sospecho no cabía en el título).

A ser posible, imprimiría ambas variables o depuraría para ver que contienen cada una, pero probablemente sea algo de este tipo y solo requiera conversión directa:
[TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/236884/198957)